# python : dynamically spawn multithread workers with flask-socket io and python-binance

Tags: python, multithreading, flask, socket.io, flask-socketio

Hello fellow developers,

I'm actually trying to create a small webapp that would allow me to monitor multiple binance accounts from a dashboard and maybe in the futur perform some small automatic trading actions.

My frontend is implemented with Vue+quasar and my backend server is based on python Flask for the REST api.

What I would like to do is being able to start a background process dynamically when a specific endpoint of my server is called. Once this process is started on the server, I would like it to communicate via websocket with my Vue client.
Right now I can spawn the worker and create the websocket communication, but somehow, I can't figure out how to make all the threads in my worker to work all together. Let me get a bit more specific:

Once my worker is started, I'm trying to create at least two threads. One is the infinite loop allowing me to automate some small actions and the other one is the flask-socketio server that will handle the sockets connections. Here is the code of that worker :

**customWorker.py**

```
import time
from flask import Flask
from flask_socketio import SocketIO, send, emit
import threading
import json
import eventlet

# custom class allowing me to communicate with my mongoDD
from db_wrap import DbWrap
from binance.client import Client
from binance.exceptions import BinanceAPIException, BinanceWithdrawException, BinanceRequestException
from binance.websockets import BinanceSocketManager

def process_message(msg):
    print('got a websocket message')
    print(msg)

class customWorker:
    def __init__(self, workerId, sleepTime, dbWrap):
        self.workerId = workerId
        self.sleepTime = sleepTime
        self.socketio = None
        self.dbWrap = DbWrap()

        # this retrieves worker configuration from database
        self.config = json.loads(self.dbWrap.get_worker(workerId))
        keys = self.dbWrap.get_worker_keys(workerId)
        self.binanceClient = Client(keys['apiKey'], keys['apiSecret'])

    def handle_message(self, data):
        print ('My PID is {} and I received {}'.format(os.getpid(), data))
        send(os.getpid())

    def init_websocket_server(self):
        app = Flask(__name__)
        socketio = SocketIO(app, async_mode='eventlet', logger=True, engineio_logger=True, cors_allowed_origins="*")
        eventlet.monkey_patch()
        socketio.on_event('message', self.handle_message)
        self.socketio = socketio
        self.app = app

    def launch_main_thread(self):
        while True:
            print('My PID is {} and workerId {}'
                .format(os.getpid(), self.workerId))
            if self.socketio is not None:
                info = self.binanceClient.get_account()
                self.socketio.emit('my_account', info, namespace='/')

    def launch_worker(self):
       
        self.init_websocket_server()
        self.socketio.start_background_task(self.launch_main_thread)
        self.socketio.run(self.app, host="127.0.0.1", port=8001, debug=True, use_reloader=False)
```

Once the REST endpoint is called, the worker is spawned by calling `birth_worker()` method of "Broker" object available within my server :

```
from custom_worker import customWorker

#...

def create_worker(self, workerid, sleepTime, dbWrap):
    worker = customWorker(workerid, sleepTime, dbWrap)
    worker.launch_worker()

def birth_worker(workerid, 5, dbwrap):
    p = Process(target=self.create_worker, args=(workerid,10, botPipe, dbWrap))
    p.start()
```

So when this is done, the worker is launched in a separate process that successfully creates threads and listens for socket connection. But my problem is that I can't use my `binanceClient` in my main thread. I think that it is using threads and the fact that I use eventlet and in particular the `monkey_patch()` function breaks it. When I try to call the `binanceClient.get_account()` method I get an error `AttributeError: module 'select' has no attribute 'poll'`

I'm pretty sure about that it comes from `monkey_patch` because if I use it in the `init()` method of my worker (before patching) it works and I can get the account info. So I guess there is a conflict here that I've been trying to resolve unsuccessfully.

I've tried using only the thread mode for my socket.io app by using `async_mode=threading` but then, my flask-socketio app won't start and listen for sockets as the line `self.socketio.run(self.app, host="127.0.0.1", port=8001, debug=True, use_reloader=False)` blocks everything

I'm pretty sure I have an architecture problem here and that I shouldn't start my app by launching socketio.run. I've been unable to start it with gunicorn for example because I need it to be dynamic and call it from my python scripts. I've been struggling to find the proper way to do this and that's why I'm here today.

Could someone please give me a hint on how is this supposed to be achieved ? How can I dynamically spawn a subprocess that will manage a socket server thread, an infinite loop thread and connections with binanceClient ? I've been roaming stack overflow without success, every advice is welcome, even an architecture reforge.

Here is my environnement:
 `Manjaro Linux 21.0.1`

pip-chill:

```
eventlet==0.30.2
flask-cors==3.0.10
flask-socketio==5.0.1
pillow==8.2.0
pymongo==3.11.3
python-binance==0.7.11
websockets==8.1
```

Comment: Monkey patching needs to be done in your main script, in the global scope, above all imports. This is to ensure that the monkey patched functions are seen by all your dependencies.

Comment: Yes ! Thank you a lot, that was it. I thought that by launching it in another process, I wouldn't have to do it in my main script but I was wrong. Thanks a lot, I've been struggling on this for more than a week !